# difference between 'Response.Redirect' and 'Server.Tansfer'

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Everyone,I must launch my code,
The first way:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Succeed,Will be redirect to the target page')</script>");
string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\Forms\MainForm_SQL.aspx");
Response.Redirect(path);
```

The second way:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Succeed,Will be redirect to the target page')</script>");
Server.Transfer(@"~\Forms\MainForm_SQL.aspx");
```

Now,back to the issue,The question is :

01)it works nothing when using the 'first way',That is, it either alerts the message nor goes into the 'Page_Load' of the target page.

02),when use the second way,it first goes into the 'Page_Load' of the target,than it goes back to alert the message.

why it that so unreachable to track the architecture ? can some one help me please?
thanks.

Comment: Don't create duplicate questions, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, `Server.Transfer` is internal -- that is, it hands off processing to the destination without bouncing the client to another page -- whereas `Response.Redirect` tells the client to go to the new URL.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but would you give an explanation that,why many times, it doesn't work by Response.Redirect? or something wrong with the syntax?even when i just comment the< Response.Write("<script>alert('Succeed,Will be redirect to the target page')></script>");

Comment: `Response.Redirect` basically tells the client to submit a request elsewhere.  But that second request might not include all the form variables and such.  If you're counting on them to be there...

Comment: Thanks for your response,but it seems that you did not got what I said the second time,actually,I found the question myself and That' manual mistake,I rename the .aspx file,but the actual name does not change unless I rename again in the code-behind.The first answer that you gave really help me,and thanks very much.